# JPA 2.1 Index annotation for columns with a function

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

In my Hibernate project, I add indices like so:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="MY_TABLE", indexes = {
    @Index(name = "idx_user_name", columnList = "name"),
    @Index(name = "idx_user_email", columnList = "email")
})
```

Which works just fine, but what happens when I want to make an index like this:

```
CREATE INDEX ON my_table (lower(name));
```

If I use the following annotation I get an `AnnotationException`:

```
@Index(name = "idx_lower_name", columnList = "lower(name)")
```

I wish to ship my project with the indices made via Hibernate + JPA 2.1. Is it possible to apply functions via the Index annotation?

Or should I just run an SQL script on deployment to add these indices myself via SQL?

I could just be formatting the `columnList` wrong, or there could be a field not described in the documentation I'm missing.

Comment: The generated Javadoc will _always_ show _all_ fields of an annotation - even those that have no explicit JavaDoc comment. And did you try  `@Index(name = "idx_lower_name", columnList = "lower(name)")`?

Comment: @tobias-liefke `AnnotationException` is the consequence of using `@Index(name = "idx_lower_name", columnList = "lower(name)")`

Comment: Thanks, I've integrated that information into the question.

Comment: Thanks for adding the edit, I was hoping your question Tobias was implicit :P I did say I tried it. It indeed is not possible to apply a function it would appear from ksokol's answer and links

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is not possible to use a function based index in JPA 2.1.

JPA provides means to abstract from a specific database. Every database has its own implementation of FBI which can [vary greatly](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/functions).
Hence, it is not part of the standard.

I peeked into the Hibernate code to see whether there might be an undocumented feature for a FBI. Unfortunately, only column based indexes are [supported](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/4.3.11.Final/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/mapping/Index.java#L98-L105).

You should run a SQL script on deployment to create your index.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought and planned to do otherwise.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Adding a function based index manually will make Hibernate fail with an exception when it retrieves the schema/table/index information from the database (at least with MySQL), since any function-based index column will have a column_name of NULL; instead, the expression column is set, as can be seen when you do "show keys from <table>;".

I also found no way to ignore this index. The Hibernate SchemaFilter can ignore schemas, tables and sequences, but not indexes. I was hoping that Hibernate only looks at indexes with certain prefixes (FK_, UK_), but no.

Comment: Here is an example of "show keys from table" with a function-based index:

`| Table | Non_unique | Key_name  | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment | Visible | Expression |`


`| test  |          1 | testindex |            1 | NULL        | A         |           0 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | (a > 0)  |`

Comment: Check this out for way around this: https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/how-can-i-make-hibernate-ignore-my-custom-index/6149